# Is there a way to restrict access of users to certain GCP services if they have access at organization level?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, cloud, amazon-iam

In my GCP organization, We have several users who have access at the organization level for IAM for all the projects within it.
I have a scenario, where in I need to **restrict** the access of some users to one particular project's specific services.

I'm aware of the VPC service control perimeters but since the service that I want to restrict is GCP **FireStore** service and it is not supported by VPC SC, What other thing can be done here to restrict the access?

Please suggest me some alternate way for doing this if there is any.

Answer (score 0):

Permissions are inherited. If you grant an identity a role at the ORG/Folder level, those permissions are inherited at the project level.

Google is rapidly developing **[Organization Policy Constraints](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/org-policy-constraints)** which might invalidate this answer in the near future.

At this time, your best solution is to remove rights at the ORG/Folder level and grant rights at the project level if you need project-level IAM control.